# php foreach loop generates results - need to determine user selection with select button

Tags: php, select, foreach, multiple-results

I have a search function (searches for a book via google books API), and 10 results are returned in table format using a foreach loop.  I have been trying for a few days to figure out how to pass the actual search results, depending upon which of the 10 the user selects. I have found numerous answers, but none seem to fit my specific requirement. I think I need to dynamically create a variable for each result, but perhaps I am on the wrong track? Maybe I need to dynamically create table id's to select the table of data, but I don't know how to do that. Or do I dynamically change the id value of the input select line?

```
     <strong><p style="font-size: 16px; text-align: center";>Top 10 Results for &quot;<?php echo @$_POST['q']; ?>&quot;</p></strong>    
    <strong><p style="font-size: 14px; text-align: center";>choose a book to select as your topic</p></strong>&nbsp;
    <table style="width:400px">
    <col width="325">
    <col width="75">
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($data['items'] as $item) { $i++;
    $b_title[$i] = $i; ?>     
              <tr>
        <td>
                   <strong><u><div style="font-size: 14px";><?php printf($item['volumeInfo']['title']);
           $b_title[$i] = $item['volumeInfo']['title']?></u></div></strong>
                     <strong>Author: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['authors'][0]);?><br />
                     <strong>Published: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['publishedDate']); ?><br />                       
           <strong>Page(s): </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['pageCount']); ?><br />
                     <strong>Publisher: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['publisher']); ?><br />
                     <strong>Category: </strong><?php printf( strtolower($item['volumeInfo']['printType']).', '.strtolower($item['volumeInfo']['categories'][0])); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <strong>ISBN: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['identifier']); ?></td>
        <td><p><input type="submit" method="post" name="selectbook" value="Select" class="btn" id="book'.$i.'" /></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="value[]" value="<?=$i?>" />
        <img src="<?php printf( rawurldecode($item['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail'])); ?>" />
                </td>
        <tr><td style="width:420px"><p><strong>Description: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['description']); ?><br /></p></td>
        <?php
          //assigning values in order to pass to javascript variables - client to server
          if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] )) {
          $book_title = $b_title[$i];
          $book_cover = $book_cover_i;
          }
          $book_cover = $item['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail'];
          $book_author = $item['volumeInfo']['authors'][0];
          $book_published = $item['volumeInfo']['publishedDate'];
          $book_description = $item['volumeInfo']['description'];
          $book_pages = $item['volumeInfo']['pageCount'];
          $book_publisher = $item['volumeInfo']['publisher'];
          $book_ISBN = $item['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['identifier'];          
         ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly solved. I can increment the values and output the exact values I want. Below I assigned "2" specifically, and sure enough the 2nd result makes it to the php file (server side). Notice the changes to javascript, the input line, and how the values are assigned to increment variables.

My last problem is getting the integer value over to the server, so I don't have to manually enter a 2. Guess I need to make a different thread for that one. Perhaps this will help someone in the future who finds this thread.

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    height: 550, width: 450});
    $( ".btn" ).click(function(){
    if(this.id.indexOf('select')>-1) { var id = (this.id.split("_"))[1]; console.log(id); }
    var bookSelect = id;
    //$("#select").val(bookSelect);
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'book-meta.php',
     async:true,
     dataType: 'json',
     //assign values to the variables to be passed to the server via data
     data: { cover : cover, title : title, author : author, published : published, 
     description : description, pages : pages, publisher : publisher, ISBN : ISBN},
     bookSelect : bookSelect,
     success: function(data)
         {
         //identify the variables for unique handing on the server side, this is
         //how javascript variables (client side) are passed to the server
         $("input[name='bbp_extra_fieldc']").val(data.cover);
         $("input[name='bbp_topic_title']").val(data.title);
         $("input[name='bbp_extra_field1']").val(data.author);
         $("input[name='bbp_extra_field2']").val(data.published);
         $("input[name='bbp_extra_field3']").val(data.description);
         $("input[name='bbp_extra_field4']").val(data.pages);
         $("input[name='bbp_extra_field5']").val(data.publisher);
         $("input[name='bbp_extra_field6']").val(data.ISBN);
         $('#select').val(data.bookSelect);
         //alert(data);
         alert(bookSelect);
         },
         error: function(errorThrown){
         alert('error');
         }
         });
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );  
  });
  });
  </script>  
        <strong><p style="font-size: 16px; text-align: center";>Top 10 Results for &quot;<?php echo @$_POST['q']; ?>&quot;</p></strong> 
    <strong><p style="font-size: 14px; text-align: center";>choose a book to select as your topic</p></strong>&nbsp;
    <table style="width:400px">
    <col width="325">
    <col width="75">
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($data['items'] as $item) { $i++; ?>     
              <tr>
        <td>
                   <strong><u><div style="font-size: 14px";><?php printf($item['volumeInfo']['title']);
           $b_title[$i] = $item['volumeInfo']['title']?></u></div></strong>
                     <strong>Author: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['authors'][0]);
           $b_author[$i] = $item['volumeInfo']['authors'][0]?><br />
                     <strong>Published: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['publishedDate']);
           $b_published[$i] = $item['volumeInfo']['publishedDate'] ?><br />                      
           <strong>Page(s): </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['pageCount']);
           $b_pages[$i] = $item['volumeInfo']['pageCount'] ?><br />
                     <strong>Publisher: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['publisher']);
           $b_publisher[$i] = $item['volumeInfo']['publisher'] ?><br />
                     <strong>Category: </strong><?php printf( strtolower($item['volumeInfo']['printType']).', '.strtolower($item['volumeInfo']['categories'][0])); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <strong>ISBN: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['identifier']);
           $b_ISBN[$i] = $item['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['identifier'] ?></td>
        <td><p><?php echo "<input type='submit' method='post' name='selectbook' value='Select' class='btn' id='select_$i' />"; ?></p>
        <img src="<?php printf( rawurldecode($item['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail']));
        $b_cover[$i] = $item['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail'] ?>" />
                </td>
        <tr><td style="width:420px"><p><strong>Description: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['description']);
        $b_description[$i] = $item['volumeInfo']['description'] ?><br /></p></td>
        <?php
          //assigning values from index results according to user selection, then 
          //pass to javascript variables - client to server in below script
          //the if statement determines is someone selected a book
          if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] )) {
          $b = 2;
          $book_cover = $b_cover[$b];
          $book_title = $b_title[$b];
          $book_author = $b_author[$b];
          $book_published = $b_published[$b];
          $book_description = $b_description[$b];
          $book_pages = $b_pages[$b];
          $book_publisher = $b_publisher[$b];
          $book_ISBN = $b_ISBN[$b];
          }
         ?>
          <script>
          //assign values to each javascript variable with results on the server
          //this is how php variables are passed from server to the client - php to javascript
          var cover = <?php echo json_encode($book_cover); ?>;
          var title = <?php echo json_encode($book_title); ?>;
          var author = <?php echo json_encode($book_author); ?>;
          var published = <?php echo json_encode($book_published); ?>;
          var description = <?php echo json_encode($book_description); ?>;
          var pages = <?php echo json_encode($book_pages); ?>;
          var publisher = <?php echo json_encode($book_publisher); ?>;
          var ISBN = <?php echo json_encode($book_ISBN); ?>;
          //var book_count = <?php echo json_encode($count[$i]); ?>;
          </script>       
        </tr>
        </tr>
```